# Cake pattern: mixing in in a trait

Tags: scala, cake-pattern

I've been playing with the cake pattern and there's something I don't fully understand.

Given the following common code:

```
trait AServiceComponent {
  this: ARepositoryComponent =>
}

trait ARepositoryComponent {}
```

the following way of mixing them works

```
trait Controller {
  this: AServiceComponent =>
}

object Controller extends 
  Controller with 
  AServiceComponent with 
  ARepositoryComponent
```

But the following does not

```
trait Controller extends AServiceComponent {}

object Controller extends
  Controller with
  ARepositoryComponent
```

with error:

```
illegal inheritance; self-type Controller does not conform to AServiceComponent's selftype AServiceComponent with ARepositoryComponent
```

Shouldn't we be able to "push" dependencies up in the hierarchy if we know that they will be common for all subclasses?

Shouldn't the compiler allow for `Controller` to have dependencies, as long as it's not instantiated without resolving them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a slightly simpler way to run into the same issue:

```
scala> trait Foo
defined trait Foo

scala> trait Bar { this: Foo => }
defined trait Bar

scala> trait Baz extends Bar
<console>:9: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type Baz does not conform to Bar's selftype Bar with Foo
       trait Baz extends Bar
                         ^
```

The problem is that the compiler expects you to repeat the self-type constraint in the subtype definition. In my simplified case we'd write:

```
trait Baz extends Bar { this: Foo => }
```

In yours you just need to make the following change:

```
trait Controller extends AServiceComponent { this: ARepositoryComponent => }
```

This requirement makes some sense—it's reasonable to want someone using `Controller` to be able to know about this dependency without looking at the types it inherits from.

Comment: Yes, I guess in the end it's a design issue about how implicit or explicit things should be in the code. Although I think it feels a bit repetitive redeclaring a dependency of a mixin, especially if it's not used directly in the trait.